# How to border every cell in a table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple table. I want a `1px solid black` border around **every** cell. For some reason I am only getting a border outlining the entire table. I tried adding `border-collapse: separate;` to the table style, which I thought was the default, but that didn't work either.

Am I doing something wrong? How do I border every cell?

What I have now is this:

```html
<table style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; border:1px solid black;">
  <tr style="outline: thin solid">
    <th align="left">Initiative</th>
    <th align="left">Scheduled Finish</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="outline: thin solid">
    <td align="left">[Initiative Name]</td>
    <td align="left">[Initiative Scheduled Finish Date]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should be styling the th and td

Comment: @sinanspd Do the th and td not inherit from the style on the table tag?

Comment: th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

Comment: The border is not inherited from parent element.

Comment: @EliasSoares Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply border to cells (TD) instead of table

```css
TD,TH {
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body style="font-family:Arial;">
        <table style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;">
            <tr>
                <th align="left">Initiative</th>
                <th align="left">Scheduled Finish</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">[Initiative Name]</td>
                <td align="left">[Initiative Scheduled Finish Date]</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your css try:

```
  th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Safest way is giving your table a class. This way it won't affect any other tables in your page.

```css
.my-table-border th,
.my-table-border td {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body style="font-family:Arial;">
        <table class="my-table-border" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; border:1px solid black;">
            <tr style="outline: thin solid">
                <th align="left">Initiative</th>
                <th align="left">Scheduled Finish</th>
            </tr>
            <tr style="outline: thin solid">
                <td align="left">[Initiative Name]</td>
                <td align="left">[Initiative Scheduled Finish Date]</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The table class is `my-table-border` and the selector is only picking `td`s and `th`s inside of tables that have this class.